# Create msg outlook file from folder

Tags: outlook, directory, msg

I have a folder with content like [this](http://www.fileformat.info/format/outlookmsg/)

More specific:

```
    __nameid_version1.0
        __substg1.0_00020102
        __substg1.0_00030102
        __substg1.0_00040102
        __substg1.0_10100102
    __substg1.0_001A001E
    __substg1.0_0037001E
    __substg1.0_10090102
    __substg1.0_3FF8001E
    __substg1.0_3FF90102
    __properties_version1.0
    __recip_version1.0_#00000000
        ...
    __attach_version1.0_#00000000
        ...
    __attach_version1.0_#00000001
        ...
```

This are files.
With a little investigation I found that this is a message content of a outlook email.

It's posible to extract a msg file with 7zip ( I already try it).

How I can pack the compound files in msg file so I can open them with outlook?

Answer (score 1):

.msg files are compound files.

You should use compound file library like [Compound File .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de) or [MSG .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are trying to pack multiple messages into a single MSG file? You cannot do that.

Comment: Here is some information so you can undestand the question 
   
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee217698(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: No, these are substorages in the main IStorage object - which is what an MSG file is - a compound OLE storage file. And this has absolutely nothing to do with any compression utilities or formats, such as 7zip, rar, zip. See IStorage object on MSDN. Are you just trying to extract data from an MSG file? You can either read it explicitly using Win API (StgOpenStorage etc., the MSG file format is documented), or use Redemption, it exposes RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile method - http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm

Comment: The MSG is already extracted. I want to pack it in MSG file again.

Comment: What do you mean by "pack"? Do you mean you want to modify an existing MSG file?

Comment: No. With the program 7zip you can extract a MSG file. How I can archive it back to MSG file?

Comment: MSG file is not an archive file. You cannot archive anything back to MSG.

Comment: I know that is not an archive. But please download 7zip program and extract MSG file. After this try to recoever it. :)

Comment: I think you do not understand the question.

Comment: Recover what? Are you trying to create an MSG file explicitly in your code?

Comment: I do not have a code. I'm just trying to find a way to recover the MSG file from the extracted old one.

Comment: "Recover" in what sense? How was it damaged?

Comment: I mean restore the MSG file from the extracted one

Comment: I am sorry, but I still have no idea what you mean. What is "extracted one"? Extracted from where? How? Why do you want to do that? What is the exact problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have a MSG file which was extracted with 7zip. Do you understand now?

Comment: Ok. And? What does it have to do with 7z? It would not care less what kind of file you store and extract. Is the MSG file damaged?

Comment: no the MSG file was extracted. How to pack it??? Read my question please and then ask your questions.

Comment: Pack where? Do you want to create another 7z or zip file? I reread your question at least a dozen times. Sorry about not being a psychic, but I have absolutely no idea what "How I can pack the compound files in msg file" means.

Comment: If you have outlook on your computer get a message from it. After that pls install 7zip. After the instalation is ready right click on the MSG file and in the 7zip menu choose Extract to "Name_of_the_message".After this please delete your msg file. OK now you have the extracted files only. Please re-create the msg file. :)

Comment: So 7z knows how to extract IStorage and IStream from MSG files. I had no idea it had that capability. If you wan to know whether it can put all these extracted parts back, you might want to ask the 7zip customer support.

Comment: I just want to know is there a program way :)